# What is the right punctuation when introducing mathematical terms in a sentence?

Tags: article-writing

This is not a mathematical question as such, but more about the correct grammatical way to describe the mathematical terms that are being introduced in a sentence.

I am used to writing sentences in this way:

> A deterministic policy, $\pi$, is a function, $\pi: S \rightarrow A$, that selects an action, $a \in A$, for a state, $s \in S$.

But a reviewer for one of my paper submissions came back with a comment that I use too many commas around my variables. I used to think that my way is the correct way, since there is a pause when introducing the respective mathematical term.

I have seen papers that use either my approach, or a single comma after the term, or no commas at all.

What is the correct grammatical way to introduce mathematical terms in these kinds of sentences?

Comment: Your sample sentence has a lot of [appositives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)

Comment: compare the answer at https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/12274/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stochastic-and-a-deterministic-policy  I would expect more detail when explaining to students, less when reporting to peers.

Comment: @KurtG. not really, I am referring to terms defined in English sentences themselves, that are not directly the subject or object of the sentence.

Comment: @WillJagy so the style of the answer you quoted seems to use my approach. So what is the reviewer complaining about?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, just to illustrate the example. So it seems that is the correct grammatical approach to punctuation? (Whether they should be used too much or not is another story).

Comment: Recommendation: don't argue with a reviewer of your papers about "correct" punctuation. If that's all they criticise get it published by sacrificing a few commas.

Comment: A deterministic policy is a function $\pi: S \rightarrow A$, where $S$ is the set of states and $A$ is the set of actions.

Comment: @WillJagy well this was just a simple example to illustrate the problem. I am not asking about restructuring this sentence, I am asking if commas should be there or not.

Answer (score -1):

In English, appositives should generally be set off by commas: "Jack, my brother, stood six feet tall." rather than "Jack my brother stood six feet tall."

In mathematical writing, however, they're often omitted: "The indicator function $\chi_A$ for the set $A$ is defined as ..."

I personally don't like that choice, but your reviewer does. @Will Jagy has suggested a restructuring that may work in some situations if the lack of commas irritates you. And @Kurt G. has a good point: don't sweat the small stuff in reviews.

Comment: That distinction between plain and mathematical English is a false dichotomy: a more pertinent comparison is "My brother, Jack, stood..." and "The indication function, $\chi_A,$ for..." (with commas, both definitely correct) $\quad$ versus $\quad$ "My brother Jack stood..." and "The indication function $\chi_A$ for..." (without commas, both acceptable as a stylistic variation by authors who prefer fewer pauses). $\quad$ To be clear: "Jack my brother stood..." is indeed an incorrect substitute for "Jack, my brother, stood...".

Comment: Scratch 'false dichotomy' above: I meant to just say that the two examples aren't really analogous.

Comment: Fair enough. Your comment made me consider that appositives of the form "description, name,  verb-phrase" seem to be different from those of the form "name, description, verb-phrase" in the way we treat them. I still believe that commas offsetting a name are less frequent in mathematics than in most other writing, but I don't have actual data to support that.